# Django absract vs non-abstract model inheritance

Tags: python, django, orm, relational-database

Consider these two model classes `Book`and `Article`:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Imagine this scenario: a book can have many annotations but an annotation can refer to only one book. Same thing for the article. I have developed two solutions:

### Non-abstract solution

```
class Annotation(models.Model):
    body = models.TextField()
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, blank=True)
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        default_related_name = 'annotations'
```

**Pros**

- Code is DRY
- One can access the annotations with `book.annotations`or `article.annotations`

**Cons**

- Waste database memory (one of the two fields `article`, `book` must be none)

### Abstract classes solution

```
class Annotation(models.Model):
    body = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class BookAnnotation(Annotation):
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        default_related_name = 'book_annotations'


class ArticleAnnotation(Annotation):
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        default_related_name = 'article_annotations'
```

**Pros**

- Clear separation for book and article annotations
- No memory waste

**Cons**

- Does not quite match the concept of annotation (the object type should be the same)
- One can access the annotations with `book.book_annotations`or `article.article_annotations` (kind of ugly isn't it?). I can not use `annotations` as related name because Django prohibit that, it says `reverse query name for BookAnnotation clashes with field name ArticleAnnotation`.

Which is the best approach to deal with such situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might consider [generic relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations) here.

```
class Annotation(models.Model):
    body = models.TextField()
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    annotated_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

class Book(models.Model):
    ...
    annotations = GenericRelation('Annotation')

class Article(models.Model):
    ...
    annotations = GenericRelation('Annotation')
```

now you can set `annotation.annotated_object` to any book or article instance, and in reverse do `obj.annotations` from both book and article objects.

Comment: This looks great, but is this a good practice? My bible, the "Two Scoops of Django" book from Daniel Greenfield, says that generic relations are bad and should be avoided ;)

Comment: Well I wouldn't want to contradict Danny and Audrey, but personally I much prefer generic relations to model inheritance; it's much less magic and avoids falling foul of the object-relational impedance mismatch (models map to db tables, it doesn't make sense to think of subclassing a table).

Comment: @BlueSurfer Generic foreign keys are bad and should be avoided.  Either of the two options you suggested in the question are superior to this in terms of the manageability and readability of your codebase.